# creating a search bar using Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, search

I have a list of markdown pages displayed on the index page. I want to make a search bar using django that displays the searched items of the list so I have written this code in order to make the search bar get a certain query

in views.py:

```
def index(request):
    x = util.list_entries()
    for entryy in x:
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            q = request.GET['q']
            data = x.entryy.filter(entryy__icontains = q)
        else:
            data = x
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": data
    })
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index")]
```

in layout.html:

```
  <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method = "get">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="search" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
```

util.list_entries() fuction:

```
def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))
```

when I enter anything in the search bar this appears

to me :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tspwt.png)

so what is the problem??

Comment: i cannot replicate the problem.  surely `views.py` has imports....  `util` is not defined, `render` is not defined.... where do these come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Your model class fields are your attributes, filter function is trying to reach the attribute that doesn't exist.
if your model is called Entry and model field - title, you can import Entry to your views, and filter through its title fields using `__contains`.

models.py:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
```

views.py:

```
from myApp.models import Entry
...

def list_entries():
    ...
    data = Entry.objects.filter(title__contains = q)
```